# calculating the sum between two integers (java)

Tags: java

What did I do wrong? I'm really not sure what else to try or where my mistake is. Thanks for any help. It's supposed to calculate the sum of integers between two numbers, e.g. between **3** and **6** it would be **3** + 4 + 5 + **6**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TheSumBetweenTwoNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("First:");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Second:");
        int max = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int difference  = max - n;

        while (i < difference) {
            sum = n + (n + 1);
            n++;
            i++;

        }

        System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);            
    }
}
```

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max).sum();`

Comment: `int sum = (max * (max + 1) - min * (min - 1)) / 2;`

Answer (score 3):

Why all this you need just a piece of code like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int min = 3, max = 6, sum = 0;
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

With while loop it should be :

```
...
int i = min;
while (i <= max) {
    sum += i;
    i++;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find a `difference` and loop over it, just running a loop from `n` to `max` will do. Also, you need to add the value to `sum` (`+=`) instead of assigning a value to it (`=`, which overwrites previous value)

Try this:

```
int i = n;

while (i <= max) {
    sum += i;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the previous `sum` value with the most recent `n + (n + 1)`, instead of accumulating the previous sum. Also, your loop is one iteration short. Try this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = n; i <= max; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this snippet

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;
int difference  = max - n;

while (i < difference) {
    sum = n + (n + 1);
    n++;
    i++;

}
```

In

```
int sum = 0;
int i = n;

while (i <= max) {
    sum = sum + i;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made it a little bit overcomplicated. All you really need is a for loop that runs from `n` to `max` that adds up the incrementing variables:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = n; i <= max; i++){
    sum += i;
}
```