# How to add the sum of ints n to c

Tags: java, math

I want to write a code that prints out the sum of a specified number, another specified number, and everything in between (inclusive). For example, if we have the numbers (6, 8), it should add up the numbers 6, 7, and 8, and print the sum 21.
Can someone explain to me how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calculating the sum between two integers (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596874/calculating-the-sum-between-two-integers-java)

Comment: What part if this can you do yourself? Do you know how to define a method? Or a class? Do you know how to create a variable? How to return one?

Comment: Use a for loop. for(int i = 6; i <= 8; i++){}  change to suit your function.

Comment: @khelwood yes kind of I'm taking ap computer science

Comment: @user15316878 Your efforts so far are helpful to include in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using a loop and from what I understand, a seperate method, which we'll call `addSum`. In addSum, we will create a for loop with the starting limits and the ending limit.

```java
public static void addSum(int start, int end) {
  int addMe = 0;
  for(; start <= end; start++) {
    addMe += start;
  }
  System.out.println("The result: " + addMe);
}
```

And the main method looks like this:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    addSum(2, 4); // Replace this with the numbers you want
  }
```

So the whole code looks like this (assuming your file is called Main.java):

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    addSum(2, 4); // Replace this with the numbers you want
  }
  public static void addSum(int start, int end) {
  int addMe = 0;
  for(; start <= end; start++) {
    addMe += start;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you you!!!! you explain it wayyy better than my teacher

Comment: Your welcome! If you answered my question, could you mark it as correct? That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ublec okayyy :)

Comment: what would I do for this question Write a method that returns the sum
   of all multiples of "multiple" between
   the numbers zero and 100.

Comment: I would 1) use an additional variable as counter in the loop; 2) not print, but return the sum

Comment: @ublec how would I start it

Comment: @ublec is this right public static int multipleAdd(int multiple){

Comment: I updated the answer so it shows the entire code. This is just one way to do this. A return type can also be used.

Comment: Why are you using `start >= end` as the loop condition?

Comment: Great catch. I just fixed it.